# Laravel return json with eloquent collection relationship values

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following function inside the UsersApiController class :-
public function getKhatmas()

```
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $khatmas = $user->khatmas;
    return response()->json($khatmas);
}
```

The above code give the following response :-

```
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "hash": "5ec72b4913d1a",
        "type": 2,
        "type_text": "sample text",
        "division": 2,
        "division_variant": 1,
        "status": "active",
        "expiry_date": null,
        "is_name": 0,
        "user_id": 2,
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "hash": "5ec72b7005126",
        "type": 2,
        "type_text": "sample text",
        "division": 2,
        "division_variant": 1,
        "status": "active",
        "expiry_date": null,
        "is_name": 0,
        "user_id": 2,
    },
]
```

Relationship function in User Model file :-

```
public function khatmas()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Khatma');
    }
```

App\Khatma file content :-

```
public function type()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\KhatmaType');
    }
```

In above json response , ("type": 2) is the foreign key of App\KhatmaType Model .
I want instead of json response with the foreign key of KhatmaType Model, i want it to return the column "title" from App\KhatmaType to be like this :-

```
{
        "id": 3,
        "hash": "5ec72b4913d1a",
        "type": "this is title from App\KhatmaType Model",
        "type_text": "sample text",
        "division": 2,
        "division_variant": 1,
        "status": "active",
        "expiry_date": null,
        "is_name": 0,
        "user_id": 2,
    }
```

`I tried with the following :-

```
$khatmas = $user->khatmas->with('type');
```

But it return error : Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::with does not exist

Comment: can you try this `Auth::user()->load('khatmas.type')`

Comment: @Aslam I tried, i am getting "type": null,

Comment: You could use join in the query, but I think you have the relation defined backwards, or the foreign key 'type' in the wrong table, because if KhatmaType belongsTo Khatma, the foreign key should be in KhatmaType and not in Khatma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by using the following query builder:-

```
public function getKhatmas()
{
    $user = Auth::user();

    $khatmas = Auth::user()->khatmas()
    ->select('hash','type_text','status','expiry_date','type_id')
    ->with('type')->get();

    return response()->json($khatmas);
}
```

Comment: In this way you will have an object on 'type' attribute, and not a string as you asked.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ you are totally right, but now its ok for me, it seems object its more scalable if i want to get more data from type model . Thank you for your time